# All in situation with side pot

Tags: all-in, side-pots

Following situation:

Player 1:  100$
Player 2: 100$
Playe 3: 50$

Player 1 makes "all in" - all other players call.

So I guess it's main pot: 150$
Side pot (for p1 and p2): 100$

Player 3 wins. Obviously he get's the 150$.  Now additionally let's say  p2 has a better hand then p1 (e.g. a better pair, while p1 has a lower pair), does p1 need to give the side pot money still to p2? Or does only the winner get something and the rest (side pot) goes back to the corresponding players?

Comment: Thanks and sorry. I did try to search, but didn't know how to find it. Find it kind of hard to find because I didn't know "what to search for".

Comment: Don't apologize. Its no big deal, welcome to poker SE. Usually when you ask a question a box will come up suggesting possible posts that have an answer, very handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The side pot is not split up between the remaining players. Of the remaining players the player with the best hand takes the side pot.